# Downloaded save file gives "ERR_GEN_ZLIB_2 Failed zlib call"

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am having a problem with the retail version of Grand Theft Auto V.

I already finished the SP , I thought I would just download the 100 % save files and copy / paste in C:\Users\user\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles\5D8BEC65 so that I can play the online version of the game.

But when I do this whenever I open up SP or MP (online) I get `ERR_GEN_ZLIB_2 Failed zlib call` error.

I basically did everything like re-installing, re-booting, checking .rpf with WINMD5 (everything was matched here).

Comment: You don't need to copy anything to play online. Just launch the multiplayer.

Comment: 100% save files.

Comment: But the sp have to be finished first right ?

Comment: @SachinRamesh - Nope

Comment: @ 5pike How to launch multiplayer ( sorry for such questions , i am a noob )

Comment: @SachinRamesh - It's somewhere in the option menu.

Comment: [Google and rockstar have some things for you to try](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=yFymVZPMLKLd8gfm7IGoBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=gta+5+Failed+zlib+call)

Answer (score 0):

What I found regarding the ["Failed zlib call" on rockstar support:](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/204775458-How-to-Fix-Failed-zlib-call-error-in-GTAV-PC)

> Question: An error message is appearing in GTAV PC saying “ERR_GEN_ZLIB_2 Failed zlib call. Please reboot or reinstall the game.” Do I really need to reinstall or can I just reboot?
>
> Answer: Rebooting will probably not fix this error message, which suggests that installation data is corrupt.
>
> If using the disc version, you can attempt to repair GTAV from the discs or by using the command line -verify (for more information on command lines, please see this Support article). If on Steam, you can try to verify game cache to fix the installation.
>
> If the error still appears after trying those steps, or if you are using a digital version downloaded from Social Club, go to Add/Remove programs in your Windows Control Panel and uninstall GTAV. Then reinstall the game, either from the discs or by downloading directly from the Social Club GTAV Activation Page.

Comment: thanks for the quick responce , unfortunately those steps did not worked for me , every time i start a new game this error pops up :( .

Comment: you could try to download [**zlib**](http://www.zlib.net/) and copy the zlib dll in your gta folder, maybe the original dll is corrupt